# Mongoose, removing an object from an array and updating other objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm a web development rookie and I'm trying to build a simple editable image gallery. I have a Collections schema and a Paintings schema:

```
var collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    paintings: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Painting"
        }
    ]
})
```

&&

```
var paintingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    img: String,
    description: String,
    index: Number,
    parent: String
});
```

I'm currently trying to add a destroy route which will delete one painting from one collection. I have this so far:

```
app.delete("paintings/:type/:index", function(req,res){
    var type = req.params.type;
    var index = req.params.index;
    Painting.findOneAndRemove({parent:type,index:index},function(err,removedPainting){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.redirect("/paintings/"+type);
        }
    });
});
```

However, I also need all of the "index" attributes of objects with higher indices than that of the deleted object to decrement by one after the object is deleted. Any idea as to what the best way to do this is?

I have tried:

1. changing the destroy route into an update route, and then just completely replacing the array of Paintings within the Collection to an updated version, but that doesn't seem to work--I think because the array within the Collection schema is not actually an array of objects, but an array of ObjectIds?
2. Redirecting (from end of the destroy route) to an update route which loops through the Paintings found by Paintings.find({parent: type}) and increments their ids, but I never actually got to test this because when I tried to redirect from the destroy route I would always get the error: "cannot GET paintings/:type/:index/delete" even though I had made the route a put request, not a get request.

Any ideas? Anything would be much appreciated, I'm clearly kind of fumbling around in the dark here. Thanks a ton!

Comment: why do you want to amend the index property of the other paintings, it seems like a bad idea.  What do you need the index property for, maybe there is another way to get this without storing it as a property in the document.

Comment: Because I couldn't get the Collection schema to work for delete and update routes, so I've had to use stuff like Painting.findOneAndUpdate({parent: type, index: index}) to update a painting, so I needed an index parameter to find the painting in the first place. In trying to rework this, I'm not sure how to edit or delete a painting using its place in the Collection paintings array

Comment: Having an index parameter has been very useful because it allows me to structure my index and show pages around orderly indices, instead of ids. I don't need unique id's because each gallery is visible only to its creator/owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by eliminating the index attribute of the Painting schema, and eliminating the Painting schema entirely so that all paintings only exist as an object within Collections:

```
var collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
paintings: [
        {
            img: String,
            description: String,
            parent: String
        }
    ]
})
```

Then, I changed my delete route so that it was actually a put route which pulled the correct painting from the Collection's painting array:

```
//DESTROY
app.put("paintings/:type/:index/delete", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    var type = req.params.type;
    var index = req.params.index;
    Collection.findOne({name:type},function(err,collection){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            var idOfRemove = collection.paintings[index]._id;
            Collection.findOneAndUpdate({name:type},{$pull:{ paintings:{ _id: idOfRemove}}}, function(err,removedPainting){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else{
                    res.redirect("/paintings/"+type);
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```